# What is `return of ()` syntax

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm looking at this snippet of code:

[image]

It's typescript. On the first line there is:

```
... return of (true);
```

What's this syntax?

Comment: They're all RxJS operators. Instead of writing `Observable.of()`, `Observable.from()`, `Observable.mergeMap()`... the guy just wrote `of()`, `from()`, `mergeMap()`. Look at the top of a snippet, you should see the imports for these RxJS operators. Note that this is NOT the usual practice; it makes the code harder to read.

Comment: @AngularFrance, thanks, can you post it as answer? Actually the code is from angular sources. You're the second person saying that their code is not good to learn from

Comment: Just did. From Angular sources you say? Interesting. Could you say which file? I'd like to take a look. Note that I said it wasn't the usual practice, not bad practice. Certainly the guys from the core team know what they're doing. ;)

Comment: @AngularFrance, it's [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/router/src/router.ts#L858)

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Most of the short function names in this snippet are **RxJS operators**.

Instead of:

- `Observable.of()`
- `Observable.from()`
- `Observable.mergeMap()`

You have:

- `of()`
- `from()`
- `mergeMap()`

Look at the top of the snippet, you should see the imports for these RxJS operators.

Note that this is NOT the usual practice (I think it makes the code harder to read).

Comment: this is the usual practice for library authors. maybe reference [my this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45483934/how-to-correctly-import-operators-from-the-rxjs-package/45484025#45484025) answer in your answer :)

Comment: Currently part of the official Angular tutorial: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6

Answer (score 2):

Likely its a function called `of` in which is being passed `true`. The whitespace is irrelevant to the parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

`of` isn't a keyword of TypeScript, there must be a function somewhere named `of`

```
 function of<T>(value: T) {
     // ...
 }
```

Comment: Actually it is. in the `for.. of` statement. [For.. of](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/for...of.html)

Comment: true true true true

Comment: well it's not `for ... of` definitely, see the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42279525/2545680)