# How to correctly import operators from the `rxjs` package

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am confused how to import those operators. Some I can import with 
`import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';` and some I can not. For ex, this does not work:
`import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';` (I checked in rxjs/add/operator, map exists there).

Essentially what I am trying to do is to reproduce this in Angular4:

```
var requestStream = Rx.Observable.just('https://api.github.com/users');

var responseStream = requestStream
  .flatMap(function(requestUrl) {
    return Rx.Observable.fromPromise(jQuery.getJSON(requestUrl));
  });

responseStream.subscribe(function(response) {
  // render `response` to the DOM however you wish
});
```

I also want to know how to deal with `just` operator, since I can not see it in rxjs/add/operator...

Thanks for any help

Comment: `rxjs/add/operator/map` exists as well, see https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/add/operator/map.ts. Operator `just` was renamed as now it's called `of` and you can add it via `rxjs/add/observable/of`

Comment: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-of

Comment: @martin, ok, thanks for info about `just` operator

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular cli rxjs operator imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45047174/angular-cli-rxjs-operator-imports)

Comment: @Jota.Toledo Its far away from duplicate. Please read them before flagging...

Comment: Use `rxjs/operators`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are static and instance operators in RxJS:

```
static
   of
   interval

instance
   map
   first
```

You may want to use these on the `Observable` global object or observable instance like this:

```
Observable.of()
observableInstance.map()
```

For that you need to import modules from the `add` package:

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
```

When you import the module it essentially patches `Observable` class or `Observable` prototype by adding method corresponding to the operators.

But you can also import these operators directly and don't patch `Observable` or `observableInstance`:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operator/map';

of()
map.call(observableInstance)
```

With the introduction of lettable operators in RxJs@5.5 you should now take advantage of the built-in `pipe` method:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators/map';

of().pipe(map(), ...)
```

Read more in [RxJS: Understanding Lettable Operators](https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-understanding-lettable-operators-fe74dda186d3)

Comment: Could you also tell me how to find out which operator is static and which is instance? Now I want to use `flatMap` but seems it doesnt work neither `import 'rxjs/add/operator/flatmap';` or `import 'rxjs/add/observable/flatmap';`... 
`

Comment: Most static operators are creational operators - they create a strem. `flatMap` is an instance operator because it works on the instance of the observable. it was renamed to `mergeMap` in 5.x. all these renames are confusing

Comment: oh jeez... every single word I type in editor I must dedicate to a new question in SO :D Thanks again :) p.s. and I noticed that after I import mergeMap, I can use it in code as either `flatMap` or `mergeMap`...

Comment: With RxJS 5.5.2+ and lettable operators, how to properly import and use static operators e.g. `Observable.of`?

Comment: @AlexanderAbakumov, lettable operators are related to instance operators, not static operators. For more information, read https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-understanding-lettable-operators-fe74dda186d3

Answer (score 1):

Lower version of rxjs has got folder

> **node_modules\rxjs\operator**

Higher version of rxjs has got folder

> **node_modules\rxjs\operators**

Please make sure the typescript file location is exists for map and other operators exists within.

If problem still persist please delete rxjs folder from node_modules and run the command

```
npm  install --save
```

usually this causes due to lowering the package version from higher version of rxjs.