# Get message saying that function is of type void

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new to angular and any trying to setup my authorization module for an ionic project I'm working on.

I'm getting close, but am running into an issue with the 'auth' service I created.

I have an auth.service with the following login method:

```
  login(user){
    this.http.post(this.API_ENDPOINT+'/authenticate', user)
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(user => {
        this.storeUserCredentials(user); 
        return user;
    })
  }
```

in my login.ts component, when I call the method:

```
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private auth: AuthenticationProvider) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad LoginPage');
  }

  userLogin(f){
    this.auth.login(f.value)
      .subscribe(response => {
      this.navCtrl.push('TabsPage');
    })
  }

}
```

I get a red line under '.subscribe' with the following error:

```
[ts] Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'.
any
```

I should probably mention that my goal is to hit the authenticate endpoint, then process the "storeUserCredentials(), then navigate to the tabs page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is TypeScript error. It indicates that there was human mistake. `login` method doesn't return anything (`void` type) but is expected to return an observable that has `subscribe` method.

In this case it's unacceptable to call subscribe in `login` because subscription should occur outside the method.

If `storeUserCredentials` is synchronous side effect, it can be handled with `do` operator:

```
  login(user){
    this.http.post(this.API_ENDPOINT+'/authenticate', user)
    .map(res => res.json())
    .do(user => {
        this.storeUserCredentials(user); 
    })
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, estus. I just read where the cause may be because I'm using the .subscribe method in the service. So when I call the function in my login.ts component, I'm trying to apply the .subscribe to a type of Subscription. I guess I'm trying to figure out how to process the storeUserCredentials() method in the service, then navigate to the tabs page from my login.ts component when everything is complete.

Comment: Getting the following: [ts] Property 'do' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>'.
any

Comment: You need to import it, as any other RxJS operator, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45483934/how-to-correctly-import-operators-from-the-rxjs-package

Comment: That worked. So on my service side it looks like everything should be processing. Now my question is on my login.ts component after '   this.auth.login(f.value)' finishes processing (async), how do I initiate navigating to the next page? In AngularJS I'd us a 'then' function. By the way, thanks for your help!!

Comment: I don't use ionic but I guess that you're already doing this with `this.navCtrl.push('TabsPage')`. `subscribe` plays same role as `then` here. Btw, you can switch to promises any time with `http.post(...).toPromise()` but I'd strongly advise against that because observables are there for a reason and can do things that promises can't.

Comment: Thanks, estus. I tried the following:  userLogin(f){
    this.auth.login(f.value)
      .subscribe(this.navCtrl.push('TabsPage'))


      //this.navCtrl.push('TabsPage');

  }  But get the error: [ts]
Argument of type 'Promise<any>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: any) => void'.
  Type 'Promise<any>' provides no match for the signature '(value: any): void'.

Comment: This is not what your original code says. It is `.subscribe(response => {  this.navCtrl.push('TabsPage') })`, isn't it? It should be used like that.

Comment: Done! Thanks a million!