# Angular 2+ - Parse JSON as number

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I want to place a marker on Google Maps using [Angular Google Maps](https://angular-maps.com/) my coordinates are from JSON file which when parses in Angular it's become a string.

Angular Google Maps does not support string for coordinates number. So It needs to be number.

**marker.json**

```
[  
   {  
      "id":"1",
      "lat":"13.751814",
      "lon":"100.501060"
   },
   {  
      "id":"2",
      "lat":"13.738445",
      "lon":"100.516805"
   },
   {  
      "id":"3",
      "lat":"13.730209",
      "lon":"100.779991"
   }
]
```

**maps.componenet.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-maps',
  templateUrl: './maps.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./maps.component.css']
})
export class MapsComponent implements OnInit {

    private data;

    constructor(private http:Http){
    }

    ngOnInit(){
      this.getData();
    }

    getData(){
        this.http.get('/localhost/marker.json')
            .subscribe(res => this.data = res.json());
    }

}
```

**maps.component.html**

```
<agm-map [latitude]="13.359665" [longitude]="101.035913" [zoom]="6">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let list of data">
        <agm-marker [latitude]="list.lat" [longitude]="list.lon"></agm-marker>
    </ng-container>
</agm-map>
```

I have tried using parseFloat like this  (Yes it's not working)

```
<agm-marker [latitude]="parseFloat(list.lat)" [longitude]="parseFloat(list.lon)"></agm-marker>
```

I'm thinking of using `parseInt` inside `maps.component.ts` file but I'm not sure where to put this.

May someone helps me or guide me how to solve this.And please let me know that am I providing sufficient information or not.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to convert it manually, it is default behavior of JSON.parse()

Comment: You can try `[latitude]="+list.lat"`.

Comment: Why does `parseFloat` not work? Error?

Comment: @ConnorsFan Thanks, but it not working.

Comment: @Jeff It said `parseFloat is not a function` (Full error log https://pastebin.com/8RNSVZ7P)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A cleaner and more performant way is to process data once and provide it in view in a way that doesn't need any other preparations:

```
getData(){
    this.http.get('/localhost/marker.json')
    .map(res => res.json())
    .map((data: any[]) => data.map(
      ({ lon, lat, ...props }) => ({ lon: +lon, lat: +lat, ...props })
    ))
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.data = data;
    });
}
```

If marker.json doesn't have other props except listed ones, `...props` can be replaced with known `id` property.

Comment: Thanks but I got this error `Failed to compile. <my-project-path>/maps.component.ts (54,10): Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Response>'.`

Comment: Added still have error (Error in my IDE https://i.imgur.com/wR4CIjN.png)

Comment: Then you didn't import the operator. Any observable operator that you use should be imported, like `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45483934/how-to-correctly-import-operators-from-the-rxjs-package

Comment: I imported and replace `...props` with `id` like this `({ lon, lat, id }) => ({ lon: +lon, lat: +lat, id })`. But no marker shown. (Text output working fine)

Comment: I would expect it to work as expected, http://plnkr.co/edit/XDsezGYihmpolaMHPSAg?p=preview . Consider providing a way to replicate the problem if you have troubles debugging it - Stackblitz, Plunker, etc.

Comment: Sorry, it's now output in JSON as a number now but still not working on marker

I will create a new project file for a clean project

Comment: Sure. Consider updating the question or posting a new one if current problem really differs from the one that was originally stated.

Comment: I created a new project. Copy paste anything related to maps and marker. Follow your instruction and It's work!

I'm not sure what causes the problem in my main project file. I'm trying to figure it out. Thanks for solving my problem!

Answer (score 4):

Global functions like `parseFloat` are not allowed in Angular templates (see [the Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#expression-context)).

You can convert strings to numbers with the `+` operator:

```
<agm-marker [latitude]="+list.lat" [longitude]="+list.lon"></agm-marker>
```

or define a method in your component:

```
convertCoordinate(str: string): number {
  return parseFloat(str);
}
```

and call it in the template:

```
<agm-marker [latitude]="convertCoordinate(list.lat)" [longitude]="convertCoordinate(list.lon)"></agm-marker>
```

Comment: I would go with the method route personally.

Comment: Thanks! Using `+` is not working. But using method is working but just for a string, I defined manually. It does not work for a string that from JSON parsing.

Comment: You could log the data to the console (in the http callback) to see what the strings looks like. Or you could display them with interpolation (e.g. `{{list.lat}}`) in the template.

Comment: By the way, the closing `>` is missing for the `<agm-marker>` opening tag in the markup that you show in the question.

Comment: I display them like this https://pastebin.com/cJ2vELEF. How can I tell that they are string or number? (`>` is not missing in my project file maybe missing during copy-paste)

Comment: Does it work if you add a marker with hard-coded coordinates in the markup? You could also change (or remove) the zoom, to see if it allows to see the markers.

Comment: Yes it's works if used like this
`<agm-marker [latitude]="13.359665" [longitude]="101.035913"></agm-marker>` or this `<agm-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lon"></agm-marker>` (Coordinate value assigned in .ts file)

Comment: Would it work with `<agm-marker [latitude]="'13.359665'" [longitude]="'101.035913'"></agm-marker>`? Just to make sure that passing strings really does not work.

Comment: One more thing to try: test a hard-coded marker that has exactly the same value as one of the items in your list (as shown in the pastebin). The hard-coded value that you tried is somewhat different, especially for the longitude.

Comment: Yes using string like this `[latitude]="'13.359665'"` is not working.

Answer (score 0):

+lat won't work in Angular template, it's invalid syntax and will throw an error, as well as parseFloat or parseInt, in here you can parse the JSON in the request like @estus pointed out OR you can multiply the string by 1:

`<agm-marker [latitude]="list.lat * 1" [longitude]="list.lon * 1"></agm-marker>`

This will transform the string into a number but beware that if it's NOT a number there will be error and you won't be able to catch it.

Comment: This would be a nice hack, but no, `+lat` is valid syntax.

Comment: On an HTML template?

Comment: Why would `lat * 1` be valid but not `+lat`?

Comment: Yes, +lat is valid JS syntax that is recognized by Angular parser, too, http://plnkr.co/edit/WWn8mkCY9IqZfVMYsr00?p=preview