# Elegant middleware for handling HTTP response in Angular 5.2.9

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to handle many HTTP responses in the same way,
in different classes and files, which is frustrating.
So I wonder if I can customize [`HttpClient`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient)
and make such a middleware handles tasks as followed:

```
this.http.get<any>('/api/ping/').subscribe((response) => {
  if (response.status_code == 302) {
    this.router.navigate([ response.data.redirectUrl ]);
  }
});
```

I decided to use [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) object,
but it only came to me that [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) is **not** yet implemented in TypeScript 2.5.3.

Please show me either a way to customize behaviours of [`HttpClient`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient) or a workaround for proxy object in TypeScript 2.5.3, thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need to customize HttpClient, just write an interceptor https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thшs has nothing to do with TypeScript version. Proxy is ES6 feature that cannot be transpiled or polyfilled. If the project is configured with ES5 target, `Proxy` cannot be used.

This can be achieved by reusing common code in service classes, since they are usually used to do API requests.

In case this should be done for all requests, which may or may not be desirable because this also affects third-party code, interceptors can be used:

```
@Injectable()
export class RedirectInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(protected router: Router) {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req).do((response) => {
      if (response.status_code == 302 && response.data.redirectUrl) {
        this.router.navigate([response.data.redirectUrl]);
      }
    });
  }
}

  ...
  providers: [
    [{ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: RedirectInterceptor, multi: true }],
  ],  
  ...
```

Comment: My browser outputs the following error: `ERROR TypeError: next.handle(...).do is not a function`; Obviously `Observable<HttpEvent<any>>` has no function named as `do` ...

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45483934/how-to-correctly-import-operators-from-the-rxjs-package . You always need to import operators in use. It's `import 'rxjs/add/operator/do'` in RxJS 5.